# CMake creates huge binary when I incude a standard library

Tags: c++, dynamic, cmake, libraries

I've just created an Helloworld in C++ using Cmake.
Output binary is, as expected, 10KB.
When I add `#include <string>` in main **without** using any strings, the generated binary turn to 100KB.

When I manually compile same main.cpp file `gcc main.cpp -o helloworld`, the output binary has same size, with or without `#include <string>`

Is there any Cmake keyword to use in order to allow the output binary includes everything dynamically, instead of having all libraries internally?

Comment: What CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE did you configure? The default is Debug.

Comment: That's what I use -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the problem.
In my CMakeLists.txt file was present

```
add_compile_options(-Wall -Werror -std=c++17 -g)
```

So

```
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

did not have any effect.

I just removed `-g` parameter and Debug symbols simply disappear from output binary